# Adding script to a webpage to change the contents of a paragraph when the cursor hovers over an image on HTML5 canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, javascript

I have an HTML5 canvas which is displaying a number of images. I also have some simple HTML `<p></p>` tags on my page below the canvas.

I want to update the contents of the `<p></p>` tags when the cursor hovers over these images, and I found a quick tutorial at: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/newmouseover.html which seemed to suggest it could teach you how to do this.

I've followed the tutorial, however, when I view my page in the browser now, I get a console error that says

> getElementByTagName is not a function

I've not seen this function before, and I'm just wondering if it is actually a pre-defined function, or if it's one that the writer of the tutorial has defined themselves...? I couldn't see anything on that page where the author has defined the function, so I thought it might be a pre-defined one, but I'm not sure. Does anyone know?

**Edit**

Ok, so correcting the typo fixed it, and the function is now being called. However, I'm currently calling it from my `window.onload` function, so as soon as the page loads, the paragraph has already been updated- it's not actually conditional on the `onmouseover` event being called.

My `window.onload` function looks like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var sources = [];
        sources[0] = document.getElementById("building").src,
        sources[1] = document.getElementById("chair").src,
        sources[2] = document.getElementById("drink").src,
        sources[3] = document.getElementById("food").src,
        /*There are roughly 30 lines like this adding images in the same way */

        if (document.getElementById) {
            var x = document.getElementById('mouseovers')
                            .getElementsByTagName('IMG');
        } else if (document.all) {
            var x = document.all['mouseovers'].all.tags('IMG');
        } else {
            return;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            console.log("for loop adding onmouseovers is being called");
            x[i].onmouseover = displayAssetDescriptionTip();
        }

    loadImages(sources, drawImage);
    drawGameElements();
    drawDescriptionBoxes();

    stage.add(imagesLayer);

};
```

I tried moving the `if` statements into a function called `displayAssetDescriptionTip()`, and this function now looks like this:

```
function displayAssetDescriptionTip() {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        var x = document.getElementById('mouseovers')
                        .getElementsByTagName('IMG');
    } else if(document.all) {
        var x = document.all['mouseovers'].all.tags('IMG');
    }else {
        return;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        console.log("for loop adding onmouseovers is being called");
        x[i].onmouseover = displayAssetDescriptionTip();
    }
    document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = "Assets are items that"
        + " can be bought or sold for cash.";
    console.log("displayAssetDescriptionTip being called");
}
```

However, the `onmouseover` event doesn't appear to be firing when I hover the cursor over the images to which it's been added- any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getElementByTagName is not a function.
getElementsByTagName is though :)

It's plural because it returns every element that matches the given tag.

Comment: The site's telling me I can't accept your answer for another 10 minutes, so will do then.

Comment: No bother. Any help needed, you know where we are!

Comment: Hey there- I've edited my original post to ask a follow up question with regard to where in the file I should place the code to update the `<p></p>` tags. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: This question already has an answer, so it's probably best to unedit and make a new one :)